# What is $E[Y^2]$ where $Y = \min (X_1, X_2)$ and $X_1, X_2 \sim U(0, 1)$

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value

Suppose $X_1, X_2 \sim U(0,1)$ and $Y = \min(X_1, X_2), Z = \max(X_1, X_2)$. Find $E[Y^2]$. I want to solve this in 2 particular ways, both using the law of unconscious statistician, but with a different $f_Y(y)$.

We know $P(Y \leq y, Z \leq z) = z^2 - (z - y)^2$ (if you visualize this on a 2D plot, this should become more obvious). From this we can get

$$
f_Y(y) = \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \left( P(Y \leq y,  Z \leq z) \right) = 2 (z - y)
$$

So here we have $f_Y(y)$ as a function of $z$.

Another way to get $f_Y(y)$ is from order statistics for IID uniform random variables, where we get

$$
f_Y(y) = 2 (1 - x)
$$

Here $f_Y(y)$ is a function of $x$.

From the LOTUS, we have
$$
E[Y^2] = \int_0^1 y^2 f_Y(y) dy
$$

I'm a bit confused how this integration will work with the above two $f_Y(y)$. The expectation should give a numerical value, but integrating with the above $f_Y(y)$ will yield an expectation as function of either $z$ or $y$. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The marginal density of $Y$ must be a function of the realization $y$ alone, and no other random variables.  Specifically,
$$\begin{align}
\Pr[Y > y] &= \Pr[\min(X_1, X_2) > y] \\
&= \Pr[(X_1 > y) \cap (X_2 > y)]  \\
&\overset{\text{ind}}{=} \Pr[X_1 > y]\Pr[X_2 > y] \\
&= (1 - y)(1-y) \\
&= (1-y)^2, \quad 0 \le y \le 1.
\end{align}$$
Consequently,
$$\Pr[Y \le y] = 1 - \Pr[Y > y] = 1 - (1-y)^2, \quad 0 \le y \le 1,$$
and
$$f_Y(y) = 2(1-y), \quad 0 \le y \le 1.$$

it doesn't make sense to write
$$f_Y(y) = 2(1-x)$$
since you have not specified what $x$ means.

It also doesn't make sense to write $f_Y(y) = 2(z-y)$ because as I have stated, the marginal cannot depend on any other random variables.  The correct idea here is
$$f_Y(y) = \int_{z=0}^1 f_{Y,Z}(y,z) \, dz,$$
that is to say, you are integrating the joint density of $(Y,Z)$ over the support of $Z$.  Indeed, if we are to "trust" your formula, it would make more sense to write
$$f_Y(y) = \frac{\partial}{\partial y}[\Pr[Y \le y, Z \le 1]],$$
not $Z \le z$.

In any case, once we know $f_Y(y) = 2(1-y)$, the calculation of the desired expectation is straightforward.

Comment: hmm I see. My math (especially probability theory) is quite rusty right now. In my OP, I had $P(Y \leq y, Z \leq z) = z^2 - (z - y)^2$. This is correct right? If so, what if we want to get the joint pdf $f(y, z)$. I thought we would just differentiate $P(Y \leq y, Z \leq z)$ with respect to $y, z$, which gives $f(y) = 2$. But this seems to be wrong?

Comment: The joint PDF is $$f_{Y,Z}(y,z) = \begin{cases} 2, & 0 \le y \le z \le 1 \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}$$  That is to say, it is uniform on the triangle with vertices $(0,0)$, $(1,1)$, and $(0,1)$.

Comment: Why is it a triangle? When I visualize the $0 \leq y \leq z \leq 1$ situation, I am not seeing a triangle on a plot of $x_2$ vs $x_1$. I see a square with the top right sub-square removed

Comment: @roulette01  I'm not sure why you are thinking of the joint density of $Y$ and $Z$ in terms of $X_1$ and $X_2$.  This is incorrect.  The joint density is defined for a pair of values for $Y$ and $Z$.  You already transformed from $(X_1, X_2)$ to $(Y,Z)$.  You can't keep the old variables after the transformation.

Comment: Ah it's because I'm looking at the solution for this problem in the book I am studying. This is figure they drew: https://imgur.com/a/qxiPYhX

Comment: @roulette01 That picture is just confusing.  It's not useful for visualizing the joint density of $Y$ and $Z$, because for a given pair of outcomes $(Y,Z)$, there are in general two outcomes $(X_1, X_2)$ and $(X_2, X_1)$ that give rise to the same $Y$ and $Z$.  And while the diagram sort of shows this property, you can't plot the joint density of $(Y, Z)$ on that diagram.